# Deploy signed app to jailbreaked iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, jailbreak

I am a registered iPhone developer ($99 thing) and I've been developing application that I tested using development certificate and that I sent to AppStore (pending) with my distribution certificate...

Now, I would like to test my app on whichever jailBreaked phone. I read about deploying the apps from xCode to Jailbraked phones by creating custom certificate, connecting that phone to the machine and compiling directly for it through xCode.

Is there a (short) way of just taking my .app file compiled for any device, simulator or the one created for deploying to App store and putting then through Cydia to the phone?

Thanks a lot,
Luka

Answer (score 1):

Steps:
- Create your own certificate (Keychain Access.app)
- Add it to the project
- Build app for release
- Create Cydia repository, check: http://www.saurik.com/id/7 
- Upload to server
- Add repository to iPhone
- Install application

Note:
Apps compiled for the simulator do not work on the device, different architecture.

Comment: The application created for deployment trough the AppStore can also be deployed trough Cydia.

Comment: Thanks, Anne! I'll give it a try...
Your comment is more valuable to me than your answer :p You're getting the vote up, though